# Compiling qt 4.8.3 on osx 10.8.5 results with incomplete install

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, qt4.8

there are no obvious errors. 
the output being similar to building `qt 4.8.5` (which I have built succesfully) but the obvious issue is that the bin folder only contains 3 files, `moc.exe`, `rcc.exe`, `uic.exe`
and missing the demos, doc, examples, imports folders etc .. and i cannot find them anywehere else.
i assume the `make install` step is failing

i'm a bit of a noob :)

i am using these steps to compile -

```
gunzip qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.3.tar.gz
sudo tar xvf qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.3.gz
./configure -prefix /Users/User/qt4.8.3
make
sudo make install
```

(i think i've tried `sudo` on `make` as well, but can't quite recall exactly)

the `makefile` seems to have relevant paths

```
install_qmake: FORCE
    @$(CHK_DIR_EXISTS) $(INSTALL_ROOT)/Users/User/Qt4.8.3/bin/ || $(MKDIR) $(INSTALL_ROOT)/Users/User/Qt4.8.3/bin/ 
    -$(INSTALL_PROGRAM) /Volumes/data/qt-creator/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.3/bin/qmake $(INSTALL_ROOT)/Users/User/Qt4.8.3/bin/
```

edit..
i went through and compared teh 4.8.3 and 4.8.5 makefiles and apart from the obvious version and directory differences they were identical.
i'm wondering if it's a permission thing and will download a new copy of the source soon and try again.